# Ошибка при сборке glew

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, mingw

с чем может быть связана ошибка

> [ 16%] Linking C shared library bin\glew32.dll
> CMakeFiles\glew.dir/objects.a: member CMakeFiles\glew.dir/objects.a(glew.rc.obj)
> in archive is not an object
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Генерирую Makefile через CMake-gui, не устанавливаю никакие флаги, качаю исходники с http://glew.sourceforge.net/

Версия glew 2.1.0, CMake - 3.20.2, mingw32 с gcc 8.1.0. Для версии 11.2.0 то же самое. Пробовал играться с флагами CMake - не помогло.

Comment: что то мне подсказывает, что проблема в битности все кода (32 или 64 бита) и/или неверном компиляторе (весь код должен быть собран компилятором одной версии (или совместимой) - если качаете сбилжденные файлы, то внимательно проверяйте, для какого конкретно они компилятора)

Comment: CMake по умолчанию на винде любит использовать Visual Studio? Может он ее подхватил вместо MinGW? Она у вас установлена? Еще, откуда качали MinGW и make?

Comment: Не, при конфигурировании я явно указываю компилятор, за тем использую mingw32-make из той же папки bin.